# Not detecting contacts between sprites

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

In my app I have five balls spawning and moving down the screen one at a time each second. I have a sprite at the bottom and you have to move it to dodge the balls. I'm using category bit masks to track the contacts between object of course. In the method I use to create the balls I have an action that moves the ball down and off the screen. I have an NSLog statement telling me if it's recognizing the contacts but it's not coming up. The code below is for the ball that I'm creating sand it includes all the actions for moving and spawning.

I think the problem may be because the ball is not dynamic so I doesn't take part in the physic world but I'm not exactly sure what the alternative is.

```
-(void) addBall:(CGSize) size{
CGFloat xPositions[5] = {8.5,74,138,203,267.5};

int randomIndex = arc4random() % 5;
int randomXPosition = xPositions[randomIndex];

CGRect box = CGRectMake( randomXPosition , self.frame.size.height,    //pos
                        45, 45);   //size
UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:box];

SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];
circle.path = circlePath.CGPath;
circle.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:(243.0f/255) green:(134.0f/255) blue:(80.0f/255) alpha:1.0];
circle.strokeColor = nil;
circle.lineWidth = 3;

//add physics to ball
circle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:circle.frame.size.width/2];
circle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
circle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
circle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = brickCategory;

//appy actions to move sprite
SKAction *move = [SKAction moveToY:-self.size.height - 50 duration:1];
SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[ move, remove]];
SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];

SKAction *spawn = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addBall:) onTarget:self];
SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:.4];
SKAction *spawnThenDelay = [SKAction sequence:@[delay, spawn]];


[self runAction:spawnThenDelay];
[circle runAction:repeat];
[self addChild:circle];
}
```

When I get rid of the runAction for repeating the sequence and I turn the gravity on it detects the contact but if I turn the move actions back on it doesn't work again. I can't depend on the gravity to move my sprites because it glitches their x positions. Any suggestion?

Comment: Some great information in the programming guide and reference regarding simulating physics - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Comment: I just read the whole guide and I saw some good information but nothing that can really solve my problem. thanks though @prototypical

Comment: If you understand what is in the guide, you can implement a phsyics based solution. If you want to us SKActions and understand how they work and the coordinate system, you can achieve what you want. A 'glitch' changed your approach, and avoided learning what was wrong with  your old implementation.  Start with what you call "glitches". I told you what was wrong on your last question you deleted. answer aint changing.

Comment: if you want physics behavior you *have* to move the node using physics, ie applyimpulse. Actions just move the node, bypassing physics simulation.